# Reading families in a REVIT file using Forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to get the list of available families in a REVIT file. Is it possible to achieve this using the Model Derivative API ? *Or should I try out the Design Automation API ?*

I have tried using Model Derivative API. But I can only get the list of those families whose elements exist in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Zhong is right. I just discussed this with the development team again. They provide a clear, concise and convincing answer: the Model Derivative will only have the families and types in use, not all that are available in the original RVT. This is by design: MD only extracts what’s visible in the model.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Design Automation API, create a Revit Design Automation plugin to list all the available families, follow the [tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/).

You can not get the Revit families information from Model Derivative API, only the elements and properties.