# Autodesk Forge - How to get all available family in revit file

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-model-derivative

I am using Autodesk Forge to build a web app, I want to get categories, families, and family types in the original revit project. I have researched but all I can get is families that have instances on view. Can I get a family that doesn't have an instance on view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discussed this with the development team. They provide a clear, concise and convincing answer: the Model Derivative will only have the families and types in use, not all that are available in the original RVT. This is by design: MD only extracts what’s visible in the model.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, you can easily access all the data you list using a standard Revit .NET add-in, which you can migrate to and run in the [Forge Design Automation for Revit environment](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/).

Comment: thanks for your reply @Jeremy. But do have any way to get all available families of project by Model Derivative API?

Comment: I would assume so. To determine that, I would start by exploring all the available data in the viewer using JavaScript and the debugger. I am not a Forge expert, so I have not checked it myself. Have you searched extensible for other discussions of this topic? I am pretty sure that what you need is possible and has been discussed before in other StockOverflow questions and elsewhere.

Comment: Sixty seconds later: I searched for [forge revit family](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=forge+revit+family) and found this thread on [Reading families in a REVIT file using Forge API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56198330/reading-families-in-a-revit-file-using-forge-api)... oh dear, not much more help there, I'm afraid... I'll check further for you...

Comment: I find no further relevant StackOverflow threads off-hand: [Results for families revit tagged with autodesk-forge](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bautodesk-forge%5D+families+revit). However, that information is so fundamental, that I assume it is easy to find using the JavaScript debugger. Otherwise, more people would be clamouring for it.

Comment: Thank you very much, @JeremyTammik. I have explored everything about Model Derivative API and viewer, not sure if I missed anything. I think Model Derivative API only return the things that exist on view. I will use Forge Design Automation API for this problem